# Device that allows me to make a Wifi Hotspot while connected to Wifi

Tags: networking, router

I have following issue, I have only access to a wifi hotspot with two devices, where I have to log in. If I try to log in with a third device, the log in fails. My goal is to use one device, that connects to this wifi and logs in, and this device makes a further hotspot for multiple devices, which don't have to struggle with the limit of the two devices rule.

A lot of laptops, for example, support this. Mine does not, is there a good way to achieve this? I have a router (some old Netgear router), but I don't think he can do this. It would be nice to use this device as a router, in order to be able to connect further ethernet devices.

- Are there routers supporting this?
- If not, what do I have to look out for, I don't want to have to build a computer which consumes more energy than it absolutely has to.

Comment: You may be able to get by with your current laptop and a cheap USB WiFi dongle